# Let $ P<G$ a $ p$-sylow, let $H<G$ such that$ N(P) <H$. Show that $p$ divide $[G:H] -1$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

$[G: N (P)]$ congruent to $1$ module, but is not working.
Show that $p$ dividing $[G: N (P)] - [G: H]$ is also good, since I know that as $P <N (P)$ and $N (P) <H \Rightarrow  P <H \Rightarrow  P | | H |$ But I can not get out of this.

Answer (score 1):

We have by Sylow's theorem # Sylow $p$ subgroups in $G=G:N(P)\equiv1$ $mod$ $p$. again $P$ is a sylow subgroup of $H$ so no of Sylow $p$ subgroups of $=H:N_H(P)=H:N(P)$ since $N(P)<H$. Thus if $g\in N(P)$ then $g\in H$ i.e. $g\in H\cap N(P)=N_H(P)$ Thus $N(P)\subset N_H(P)$ and hence $N(P)=N_H(P)$ We have therefore $H:N(P)\equiv1$ $mod$ $p$ Thus $G:H=\frac{G:N(P)}{H:N(P)}\equiv 1$ $mod$ $p$

Comment: I did not understand why NH (P) = N (P)

Comment: See edits. I have given an explanation